# How do I access the panel1 which is non static in the main()

Tags: java, user-interface, static-variables, non-static

```
public class task1 extends JFrame{

    private JTextField firstnameTextField;
    private JTextField surnameTextField;
    private JTextField emailTextField;
    private JButton submitButton;
    private JPanel panel1;
```

this section is mean't to have a message come up with the users inputs saying submitted but only blank window pops up

```
   public task1() {
submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel1,
                        String.format(
                                "You form has been submitted with the following data: \n" +
                                        "First name: %0$s \n" +
                                        "Surname: %1$s \n" +
                                        "Email: %2$s",
                                firstnameTextField.getText(), surnameTextField.getText(), emailTextField.getText()));
            }
        });
    }
```

> panel1 is not recognised and I know it is because of it being non static variable in static method but unsure how to correct this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        task1 frame = new task1();
        frame.add(panel1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();



    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, you don't _WANT_ to access this stuff from main. Generally, (especially for newer programmers), main should contain a single line. That line is `new MyType().go();` or `new MyType().go(args);` - and then forget `static` for a good long while, it's a tricky concept you don't need all that often, other than for `main`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the GUI building logic to your constructor, it doesn’t belong in `main` anyway:

```
public task1() {
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    add(panel1);
    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { … });
}
```

However, this is still missing a meaningful initialisation of the components.